# Electron get internet connection type

Tags: electron

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation, the `navigator.connection` should have the `type` property. However, when I output `navigator.connection` in my electron application I get:

```
{
    downlink: 10,
    effectiveType: "4g",
    onchange: null,
    rtt: 0,
    saveData: false
}
```

I need to know if user is connected to `ethernet` or `wifi`. Any other way to do this ?

I have electron `3.0.4` installed.

Comment: navigator.connection is an experimental feature. And also it's not even included on the Chrome engine. That's why you aren't seeing it.

Comment: @KashifSiddiqui cool, any other way to get the connection type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a node package to detect the network type.

```
const network = require('network');
network.get_active_interface(function(err, obj) {
    // obj.type is the network type
    // 'Wireless' for wifi
    // 'Wired' for ethernet 
});
```